# How to make click button to change label text in other form?

Tags: c#

How do I make it so when I click a button in Form1 (main form), it will open Form2 while also changing a label's text (Label4) as well.

My current code for the button:

```
Admin objFrmAdmin = new Admin();
this.Hide();
objFrmAdmin.Show();
```

I don't want to change the showing code for the form I just want to add it so when I clicked the button to open that form it will also change the text on the label in Form2.

Comment: did you tried accessing form control using form.button1.label = value

Comment: Yes, but it for some reason cannot find any control on Form2 from the Form1 code.

Comment: OK - need to make the control Public.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use the object heirarchy to change the label directly.

```
Admin objFrmAdmin = new Admin();
this.Hide();
objFrmAdmin.lblLabelToChange.Text = "Your Test Here";  //<= this line.
objFrmAdmin.Show();
```

If the label doesn't appear in intellisense, then you probably need to make it public.  An alternative is to use the constructor, and pass the new test:

```
//Constructor for Admin form
public Admin(string newLabelText)
{
    this.lblLabelToChange.Text = newLabelText;
}
```

Call it via:

```
Admin objFrmAdmin = new Admin("The new text");
```

Comment: althought your first suggestion will solve OP's problem making control `public` is not generally recommended not recommended because one form is controlled with code from another. That leads to confusion, higher maintanability etc.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Admin` form constructor, something like this:

```
//add parameter text
public Admin(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //change label 4 text
    this.Label4.Text = text;
}
```

change the way you're initalizing `Admin` form like this:

```
Admin objFrmAdmin = new Admin("text to show on label");
this.Hide();
objFrmAdmin.Show();
```

**EDIT**: another way to achieve that is to make public method on admin form and call it. So, leave constructor without parameter, like it was and make public method on your `Admin` form, like this:

```
public void ChangeText(string text)
{
    this.Label4.Text = text;
    //put other code here if needed, ie. hide buttons or something like that
}
```

Now, just call that method after you initialized your `Admin` form.

```
Admin objFrmAdmin = new Admin();
this.Hide();
objFrmAdmin.ChangeText("text to show");
objFrmAdmin.Show();
```